# Set PythonHome to /var/www/virtualenvs/myenv/ ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, uwsgi

I am having really hard time with python3.4 and virtualenv.

project is working well locally but once deployed, I am getting 502 Bad Gateway. I looked into uwsgi logs, I saw this:

```
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/www/mysite/live.sock fd 6 
Python version: 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 13:01:26)  [GCC 4.9.2] 
Set PythonHome to /var/www/virtualenvs/myenv/ 
ImportError: No module named site
```

my uwsgi settings is:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/www/mysite/live.sock
chdir = /var/www/mysite
module = project.wsgi:application
virtualenv = /var/www/virtualenvs/myenv/
buffer-size = 4096
processes = 40
home = /var/www/virtualenvs/myenv/
plugin = python34
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings
enable-threads = True
single-interpreter = True
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
vacuum = True
disable-logging = true
logger = file:/var/www/mysite/log/uwsgi_err.log
```

am I missing something regarding python3? any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Looks like you're running with the wrong version of Python on your server: `Python version: 2.7.9`

Comment: @Pyrce damn you are right.. but any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing your default python and/or your virtual env that you've setup were the wrong versions. You could try aliasing `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.4` your python for the user that's launching the service, or changing the default `python` for your server (can be risky if other applications depend on 2.7 though). You'll definitely have to nuke your virtualenv setup with 2.7 and rebuild it.

Comment: If that solves the problem I can post it as an answer, it's also possible that your app is logging the errors. Check your django logs for some other message that could clear it up

Comment: @Pyrce I just rebuilt my virtualenv with pyton2.7 and everything works fine. python3 is still hard to work with..

Comment: @Pyrce and thanks btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uWSGI is using python plugin to run your application. Unfortunately, version of python used to build uWSGI plugin and version of python from yours app virtualenv must match (on first and second digit).

By default, python plugin is embedded in uWSGI binary. And in above case, it is built using python 2.7.

You can fix it in 2 possible ways. First one is to compile uWSGI using different python version, second one is to build uWSGI without python plugin and build python plugin (using different python version) separately.

For each of that, you will need uWSGI sources.

For building uWSGI with different python version, all you need to do is:

```
PYTHON=python3.4 make
```

For building uWSGI without python plugin (and some other plugins):

```
make nolang
```

For building uWSGI python plugins (you must have uWSGI without plugins already built)

```
PYTHON=python3.4 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python34"
```

Now, you can copy your plugin(s) to some global location (for example `/usr/local/lib/uwsgi`), replace uWSGI binary in system and start your uWSGI server with:

```
plugins-dir = /usr/local/lib/uwsgi
plugin = python35
```

To run uWSGI instance with loaded plugin for python 3.5